# IoT .Net SDK: Is there a way to set the SAS Token Life?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-sdk

Using the .Net SDK for IoT, is there a way to set the OPTION_SAS_TOKEN_LIFETIME (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/blob/master/iothub_client/inc/iothub_client_options.h#L36)?

I know I can generate the token and own the process using:

```
            var sasBuilder = new SharedAccessSignatureBuilder();
            sasBuilder.Key = "jzaOR************F2uT1c=";
            sasBuilder.Target = "k****y.azure-devices.net" + "/devices/" + "dotNet";
            sasBuilder.TimeToLive = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(120);

            var auth = new DeviceAuthenticationWithToken("dotNet", sasBuilder.ToSignature());
            deviceClient = DeviceClient.Create("k****y.azure-devices.net", auth, TransportType.Mqtt);
```

but this would assume I own the SAS Token expiration.

I also see that I can set it in the C SDK: (https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-c/issues/1182)

Comment: Just to clarify, in your scenario your application doesn't generate the token but just consumes it in de DeviceClient and you're looking for a way to tell the DeviceClient what the token's lifetime is?

Comment: Yes, using the native Azure IoT "DeviceClient", which addresses SAS token renewal under the covers, I would like to set the renewal time.  The default is 1 hour, I would like to change it to 24 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the related thread in github: https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/issues/1818

"By default, if you initialize the device client using connection string, it will generate sas tokens that are valid for an hour. To override this behavior, you can implement the abstract class `DeviceAuthenticationWithTokenRefresh` and pass it to the device client `Create` method for initialization."

Thanks.